# re-encoding redis data after configuration change

Tags: redis

I have been using hashes in redis with initial configuration `hash-max-ziplist-entries 512`

I needed to be with in this limit for saving memory. The initial encoding was a `ziplist`.

Without attention, I added some more keys to my keys. Their encoding changed to `hashtable` now.

I changed the redis configuration `hash-max-ziplist-entries` to accommodate more elements. But the encoding of elements is not reflecting this change in config.

I tested on my laptop, after restarting the server the encodings changed.

Is there any other way to change without bringing the server down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The restart causes the dataset to be loaded from persistence, a process that rebuilds all the internal data structures. To avoid a restart, you can use `DUMP` & `RESTORE` on each individual key that you want to rebuilt.